# Path is filled with color instead showing as contour

Tags: android, canvas

I faced the following problem: I need to show the contour of the human face over bitmap. I have coordinates of the face contour points. Here's my code:

```
private fun detectContours(
        it: FirebaseVisionFace,
        icon: Bitmap
    ) {
        val faceContour = it.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.FACE)

        val mutableBitmap = icon.copy(
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true
        )

        val canvas = Canvas(mutableBitmap)

        val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#99ff0000")

        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(faceContour.points[0].x, faceContour.points[0].y)
        faceContour.points.forEach {
            path.lineTo(it.x, it.y)
        }
        path.close()

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)

        binding.ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap)
    }
```

Here I use `path.moveTo(...)` and I expect that `mutableBitmap` will look like a face with the contour. But when I run the app I see the following result:

[image]

So, why the path is filled with the colour. Thanks in advance, I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing `path.drawline` to `canvas.drawLine`

```
    val faceContour = it.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.FACE)
    var startX = faceContour.points[0].x
    var startY = faceContour.points[0].y
    val initialX = faceContour.points[0].x
    val initialY = faceContour.points[0].y
    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    paint.color = Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
    faceContour.points.forEach {
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, it.x, it.y, paint)
        startX = it.x
        startY = it.y
    }
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, initialX, initialY, paint)
```